# is there a mybatis 'pre-interceptor' to change sql programmatically before sql execution?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, mybatis

in my current project, the update statements are assembled with those non-null bean properties , we ignore those null bean properties to prevent wrongly update fields to null.

for example (not actual code, just help to understand)

```
update person 
set
<if test=" address != null and address != '' ">
    address = #{address},
</if>
<if test=" name != null and name != '' ">
    name = #{name},
</if>
where id = #{id}
```

and if we set the `person.address` = `'--set-to-null--'` and `person.name` = `'john'` and `person.id` = `1`

mybatis will generate a sql

```
update person set address = '--set-to-null--', name = 'john' where id = 1;
```

my question is, how I can programmatically change the sql to

```
update person set address = null, name = 'john' where id = 1;
```

before mybatis excute the sql

I hope I made the question clear, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try binding:

```
<bind name="newAddress" value = "address.equals(\"--set-to-null--\") ? org.me.Utils.defaultAddress() : address"/>
update person 
set
<if test=" address != null and address != '' ">
  address = #{newAddress},
</if>
<if test=" name != null and name != '' ">
  name = #{name},
</if>
where id = #{id}
```

Comment: it will need quite a few of binds